# SQL CLR - dll download and registration

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, dll, sqlclr

I am working with SQL CLR.I do not have Visual Studio. I have SQL server installed, so I do have the .NET environment.

I have been trying to work with a piece of code but I kept getting an error on this line:

Import Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography

I identified that I require the following dll for this to work:

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography

Where can I download this and how do I install it? Do I just include it in the right folder or do I have to register it?

Any help would be useful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to use it, but a quick search points you to [the download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647292) and documentation